# JavaScript display function not work for multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

Menu icon doesn't work on other html pages. I have it set to open when pressed and show the navigation of my page and works on my index.html but not on my about.html page.

Not sure if I have to build separate JavaScript files for each page or is there a way to make it universal.

Host on GitHub pages so its a static page so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

_____ html code ____

```
  <nav>
        <ul id="menuList">
          <li><a class="active" href="">Mi Casa</a></li>
          <li><a href="aboutMe.html">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Cooking</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <img src="css/menu.svg" alt="menu" class="menu-icon" onclick = "myFunction()"/>
```

___ javascript ____

```
function myFunction(){
  if (document.getElementById("menuList").style.display === "none"){
      document.getElementById("menuList").style.display = "block";
  }
  else{
      document.getElementById("menuList").style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you add the script to the other pages?

Comment: Nothing here seems wrong. You need to make sure this script is loading on and accessible on both pages.

Comment: Your code does work. Possible sources of error: Your JS is not imported properly (maybe due to a bad url; check the network panel of your browsers developer tools). There is another element with the same Id (...dont think so but... it happens jeje). Js is disabled. Your mouse does not work well (ok no). Add an `Alert()` to your javascript just before the function declaration; if no alert comes up (most likely it wont) then its a loading problem. Most likely its the first option.

Answer (score 0):

You might forget to add the script link to other pages,
Make sure you link the JavaScript to all the pages, and use  document.querySelectorAll("#menuList")